# React Router pass props when using to

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to pass the selected Id of an account when a user clicks the click zone.

```
<Link to="/account" id={1234}>
```

However, on my Account component, which this 'to' takes us to:

```
<Route path="/account" component={Account}/>
```

I am getting Undefined.

```
export default class Account extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        alert(props.id);
```

Is there a way to pass the prop to my component using the Link?

Comment: need you to add more code so i can see how we should pass id to Account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would be define your account id as parameter in the route e.g.

```
<Route path="/account/:id" component={Account}/>
<Link to='/accounts/123'> Go to Accounts</Link>
```

and access it with `props.match.params.id`, but if you want to send through props you do this:

```
<Link to={{ pathname: '/account', state: { id: '123'} }}>Go to Accounts</Link>
```

and in Account:

```
const { id } = props.location.state
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass props down to children you can do this

```
<Route
 path="/new/path"
 render={(routeProps) => (
   <MyComponent {...routeProps} {...props} />
 )}
/>
```

and don't skip the spread operators.

Answer (score 0):

A clean way for a link to pass information to a route is to use a parameter in the URL:

```
// 1. Link to what would be the URL for a specific account.
// would probably replace `1234` for a variable here
<Link to={`/account/${1234}`>View Account 1234</Link>

// 2. "capture" the ID in the url using a param matcher
// We'll receive this param as "props.match.params.id" in the render function
// using component={} also works here, and the props will be injected directly into the component instead,
// but render={} here looks cleaner to me, and is more flexible if you wanna pass more props
<Route path="/account/:id" render={props => <Account id={props.match.params.id} />} />
```

[See the docs for more information on how the `render` prop works.](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func)